# WSUS - Cannot have two servers clients in the same time

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I'm running a WSUS within 2012 R2. I have two server, let's say Server1 and Server2. Both GPO are configured to use my WSUS server.

When I connect to WSUS server and launch the Update Services MMC, in the category "All Computers" I can see Server1, but not Server2.

When I run `wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow` on Server2, the Update Services MMC shows up Server2, but no more Server1 ...

I don't understand. Those two servers are VMware VM deployed from a template, they are both in the same domain as WSUS server. All VMs ping each other, no network related problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://learn-powershell.net/2013/10/16/fix-wsus-client-id-using-powershell/

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I failed my google research. I explained the link in my under answer in case the link broke. All credits to you. If you want to explain, I'll delete my answer and accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TomTom with his above comment. This is the explanation and how to solve ([link](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/10/16/fix-wsus-client-id-using-powershell/)) :

I deployed VM with template, and then join WSUS almost at the same time. So both Server (1 & 2) got the same WSUS ID.

So we need to reset this ID and renew the request to the WSUS Server.

1. Start by stopping the Update Service (wuauserv)
2. Delete Registry keys :

   - **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate**
     SusClientId
     SusClientIdValidation
     PingID
     AccountDomainSid
   - **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate**
     LastWaitTimeout
     DetectionStartTimeout
     NextDetectionTime
     AUState
3. Delete `SoftwareDistribution` Folder on system (`C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`)
4. Start Update Service

You can download the PS Script that does everything, at the first link.

Thanks again @TomTom.

Comment: Alternately, it sounds like the root cause of your problem is using cloned machines.  If you clone a machine (and deploying from a template ***is*** cloning), you should run sysprep on it before domain-joining or rolling it into production.  If you don't, WSUS and SCCM will be unable to differentiate between the clones.

Comment: I think you're right @HopelessN00b but as I could join the domain with both VM, I guess that this wouldn't be the main cause.

Comment: Trust me, it absolutely *is* the main/only cause.  Just because you can join the domain with a cloned machine, doesn't mean you should.  There's no "is this a good idea" check when joining something to a domain, and Active Directory will happily let you create a huge domain full of cloned machines, which then won't work with WSUS or SCCM.  Been there, fixed that, got the tiny paycheck.